# How to display a dropdown menu or any div at right edge of screen

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to display a menu which is to be displayed from the right edge of the screen.

I was already having a script to display menu at position where user clicks. For this menu, I subtracted some pixels from the co-ordinate where user clicked. But this doesn't look good to me for two reasons:

- I want my menu to be always displayed at static position from right (say `10px`)
- I don't want to code where I have to find right edge of screen and subtract my menu width, as it won't be device independent.

I tried with `right: 10;` but this strangely doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas ?

---

```
$('#cross').on('click', function (e) {

        // co-ordinates to display the menu
        var top = e.pageY
        var left = e.pageX;
        left = left - 150;

        // Display the menu 
        $("#cross-menu").css({
            display: "block",
            position: "fixed",
            top: "calc(3.5rem)",
            left: left
        }).addClass("show");

        return false;
    });
```

**Code:**
https://jsfiddle.net/7ysp46xv/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to set lots of CSS in jQuery on the dropdown menu - Bootstrap classes already set most of that up to work the way you want.

Bootstrap has a class called `show` that you are already adding to the menu in your jQuery. You just need to make a few small changes to it - you can add these in a custom class:

```
#cross-menu.show {
    right: 10px; 
    left:  auto; /* remove the left position so it won't use the full screen*/
    top:   auto; /* remove the position 100% */
}
```

Then all you need to do in jQuery is apply the `show` class:

```
$('#cross').on('click', function (e) {
        $("#cross-menu").addClass("show");
});
```

**Working Example:**

```js
$('#cross').on('click', function (e) {
        $("#cross-menu").addClass("show");
});
```

```css
.hamburger {
    height: 80%;
    width: 2rem;
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.hamburger div {
        margin: 0.4rem 0px;
        border: 1px solid white;
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 5px;
}

.link-simple {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#cross {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#cross-menu {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
}
#cross-menu.show {
top:auto;
right:10px;
left:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"><html>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark justify-content-center text-light" style="height: 3.5rem;">

    <!-- Hamburger Menu-->
    <div class="col-2 col-sm-4 align-content-start">
        <div class="hamburger link-simple">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Topic Name -->
    <div class="col-9 col-sm-4 text-center">
        <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">Heading</span>
    </div>

    <!-- User Info / Menu -->
    <div class="col-1 col-sm-4 text-right align-content-end" id="cross">
        X
    </div>

</nav>

<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-sm" id="cross-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item pl-3"><i class="fa fa-gear mr-4"></i>Settings</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item pl-3"><i class="fa fa-sign-out mr-4"></i>Logout</a>
</div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tinkered around with your code. This is what ended up working:

```
$("#cross-menu").css({
    display: "block",
    position: "fixed",
    top: "calc(3.5rem)",
    right: "10px",
    left: 'auto',
    'max-width': "150px",
}).addClass("show");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  $('#menu').animate({
    right: 0
  }, 300);
});

$('li').click(function(){
  $('#menu').animate({
    right: -80
  }, 300);
});
```

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;}
body{margin:0;}
button{margin:10vh 0 0 49vw;}
#menu{
  position:fixed;
  width: 80px;
  top:10;
  right: -80px;
}
ul{margin:0;padding:0;list-style-type:none;border:1px solid red;}
li{
  padding: 10px 25px;
  border:1px solid green;
}
li:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #ccc;
}
aside{
margin-top:10vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="menu">
  <ul>
     <li>One</li>
     <li>Two</li>
     <li>Three</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button>Show Menu</button>
<aside>Stick a tags inside the LIs to create a menu</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your problem. Firstly i don't recommend dropdowns to have position: "fixed" unless it's necessary , Instead you can use position:absolute;

Now looking at your requirement , instead of subtracting the left width you can use left:auto; and right:5%; (whatever % your need). This will also adjust to different device widths.

YOUR CODE:
position: "fixed",
top: "calc(3.5rem)",
left: left,

CHANGES I SUGGEST:
position: "absolute",
top: "calc(3.5rem)",
left: "auto",
right: "5%"

I hope this might help you.